# Get Java Variable to Reference Form Input

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to get the document.bmi.answer.value to equal to ans. But it is not showing up. Does anyone see any errors in my code?

This is in my head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcbmi()
{
var hh = parseFloat(document.getElementByName('height').value);
var ww = parseFloat(document.getElementByName('weight').value);
var ans = (( ww / ( hh * hh ))*703);
document.getElementByName('answer').value = ans;
}
</script>
```

This is in my body:

```
<form name="bmi">
<p> Height <input type="text" name="height"></p>
<p> Weight <input type="text" name="weight"></p>
<p> BMI <input type="text" name="answer" value=""></p>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcbmi();">
</form>
```

Thanks for the help!

Here is my whole code as my error my not reside in the javascript or form. I cant for the life of me see it though..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcbmi()
{
var hh = parseFloat(document.getElementByName('height').value);
var ww = parseFloat(document.getElementByName('weight').value);
var ans = (( ww / ( hh * hh ))*703);
document.getElementByName('answer').value = ans;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Body Mass Index</h1>
<form name="bmi">
<p> Height <input type="text" name="height"></p>
<p> Weight <input type="text" name="weight"></p>
<p> BMI <input type="text" name="answer" value=""></p>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcbmi();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you're talking about is JavaScript, not Java the server-side programming language.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `)` at the end of  `var ans = ( ww / ( hh * hh ))*703);`

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it but it still has not solved my over all problem of my answer not showing up in the BMI box.

Comment: Now your fix has introduced a new bug (I've addressed this in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your JavaScript that is preventing it from executing (here [is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJpTP/5/))

```
function calcbmi() {
    var hh = parseFloat(document.bmi.height.value);
    var ww = parseFloat(document.bmi.weight.value);
    var ans = (ww / (hh * hh)) * 703;
    document.bmi.answer.value = ans;
}
```

Remove the extra `)` and you should be good

Now that you've updated your code to fix the parenthesis you have introduced a new bug, the command you want (assuming you want to use the name attribute) is `.getElementsByName()` (not `.getElementByName()`)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! But what was the bug?

Comment: Ok got it! Thank you for your help! haha such a simple mistake I over looked.

Comment: Your first draft just had the extra `)`, otherwise it was perfect (you should use Firefox+Firebug or Chrome to develop JavaScript it will tell you when there are syntax errors and exactly what they are)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementByName('answer').value = ans;
```

Comment: I tried this and the answer still does not show up in the BMI box

Comment: The function is called `getElementsByName()`, because it can return more than one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.getElementById()` to get value of an HTML element, Change this:

```
document.bmi.answer.value = ans;
```

To:

```
document.getElementById('answer').value = ans;
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I changed it but the answer still does not show up in the BMI input box.

Comment: @user2291730, it's not `getElementByName` it should be `getElementById()` see my answer.. :) and you don't have `id` attribute for `answer`, add it.